# Gradle can't download dependencies with uppercase letters

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

When I try to build my app I am getting the following error:

```
> Could not resolve com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-processor:4.0.5.
     Required by:
         project :ExampleApp
      > Could not resolve com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-processor:4.0.5.
         > inconsistent module metadata found. Descriptor: com.github.raizlabs.dbflow:dbflow-processor:4.0.5 Errors: bad group: expected='com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow' found='com.github.raizlabs.dbflow'
```

my gradle dependencies:

```
def dbflow_version = "4.0.5"

dependencies {

    implementation "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow:${dbflow_version}"
    implementation "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-core:${dbflow_version}"
    kapt "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-processor:${dbflow_version}"
    implementation "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-kotlinextensions:${dbflow_version}"
}
```

Android Gradle Plugin Version: 7.0.2

I actually found a solution, which is using just lower cases, like this:

```
def dbflow_version = "4.0.5"

dependencies {

    implementation "com.github.raizlabs.dbflow:dbflow:${dbflow_version}"
    implementation "com.github.raizlabs.dbflow:dbflow-core:${dbflow_version}"
    kapt "com.github.raizlabs.dbflow:dbflow-processor:${dbflow_version}"
    implementation "com.github.raizlabs.dbflow:dbflow-kotlinextensions:${dbflow_version}"
}
```

and this works, but my question is why can't gradle find this ? my colleagues have the dependencies with upper cases and it works for them.
The only thing I changed is recently I updated Android Studio to Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are on unix and your colleagues are on windows? Unix filesystem is case sensitive whereas windows filesystem is not so could be related to that.

Either way it's best to use the correct case as specified by the provider of the dependency when declaring your dependencies. Gradle will use the provided group/artifact/version to calculate a URL for the dependency. If the URL has the wrong case a server could (in theory) respond with 404 where the case is incorrect.

Gradle will also use the group/artifact/version to build a cache key for artifacts. If you have the incorrect case this could cause cache misses. I wonder if the cache key calculation changed between gradle versions and went from being case insensitive to case sensitive.

Comment: Nope, we are all on Ubuntu, also I have tried to clear cached files and rebuild the app with in both use cases and only the lower case worked :/ is weird because this happened after I updated my android studio, can this be related somehow with that ?

Comment: As I said in my last comment it's possible something changed in gradle. And perhaps the newer version of andriod studio uses a newer version of gradle?